# NFC Android Beam

Tags: java, android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

Is it possible to read and write data from and to a NFC chip that isn't implemented in an Android device?

In the Android docs I can only find the Android Beam possibility but this is only for two Android devices?

So I want to install an NFC chip in my own hardware and communicate with this chip via an Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

Android Beam is based on the standardized SNEP protocol (Simple NDEF Exchange Protocol) -- hence, it's not limited to Android. You can implement that protocol (including the underlying peer-to-peer protocol stack) on any device.

Your NFC chip needs to be capable of speaking the NFCIP-1 peer-to-peer protocol (all typical NFC controllers support this). On top of P2P, you need to implement the NFC Forum LLCP (logical link control protocol). SNEP sits on top of LLCP.